# 1993 Ford Taurus - Clanking noise and now won't start

Tags: engine, ford

So I was driving my car it was working fine till I got on the freeway and started to accelerate. At the point to should have changed gear roughly 60mph, it started making a clanking noise. I pulled off the freeway. That's when it died the first time. I got it started again but didn't make it a block before it died again. At that point nothing would come on. I tried jumping it with two other cars. The electronics would come on but would not turn over. As soon as the cables were disconnected everything would die. I was told it could be the battery.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, battery faults don't generally make loud clanking noises...

Can you describe where the noise was coming from? That might help us to narrow it down.

Pop the bonnet (hood) and look for anything obviously amiss - anything that looks different to usual. Check the oil level and colour (it should be a semi-transparent brownish-black depending on age - brown if it's new, almost black if it's old. If it looks like mayonnaise you have a head gasket failure. If there isn't any, you have an oil leak, and probably a siezed engine).